# Remove Query String from 301 Redirect through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am facing a couple of 301 redirect issues.

**Issue 1:**

I want to redirect some links to another URL of the same site:

```
Redirect 301 /path-example.html /dir/subdir/
```

The redirect is working but it's generating query string like this:

```
example.com/dir/subdir/?str=path-example
```

How do I remove the query sting ***?str=path-example*** ?

**Issue 2:**

I want to redirect some links to the homepage:

```
Redirect 301 /some-path.html /
```

But it's leaving a **?** after a trailing slash like this:

```
example.com/?
```

How do I remove **/?** from the forwarded URL?

Existing rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ / [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no rule in your code that is adding `?str=`. Do you have some other rules or code doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Please place these rules top of your htaccess files(in case you have more rules in it). Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


##Redirection with removing query string rule here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^.]*\.html\?\S+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /dir/subdir? [R=301,L]

##Redirection to site's home page here for html urls.    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^.]*\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** My first answer without OP's other rules set is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Redirection with removing query string rule here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^.]*\.html\?\S+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /dir/subdir? [R=301,L]
##Redirection to site's home page here for html urls.    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^.]*\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @Ihfaz, could you please do let me know what sample url you are hitting? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have noticed that it's happening when I'm trying to forward an URL with .html extension. I am trying to forward /abc-def.html to homepage like this:
Redirect 301 /abc-def.html /

But it's generating: home.com/?str=abc-def

Comment: @Ihfaz, ok so you mean your query string question is resolved now. But your home page question is not solved correct? Can you please explain more on home page question? Like FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect?(right now my rules are redirecting from `http://localhost:80/test-abc.html` TO `http://localhost:80` url), let me know on these details please, cheers.

Comment: @Ihfaz, considering your 1st question is answered now and for your 2nd question to redirect to home page(where you want to redirect FROM `http://localhost:80/test-abc.html` TO `http://localhost:80`) I have edited my rules now, please do check them and let me know how it goes. Also let me know if you have anymore rules also in your htaccess file?

Comment: The first issue is not resolved as well. The codes are giving me internal server error. I have other rules as well.  Please check this screenshot: https://prntscr.com/174inmj

Comment: @Ihfaz, sure, please edit your question, I didn't see its edited as of now, thank you.

Comment: Edited, please check.

Comment: @Ihfaz, sure, I have edited my rules now(including your already existing rules, I have FIXED few things in your rules too, once you confirm they are working; I will add detailed explanation to answer too), please do check update Rules in answer. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I commented out the previous rules and added the new ones. It's now giving me Error 500.

Comment: @Ihfaz, Trust me buddy, these both Rules(posted as EDIT in my current answer) are working fine for me, I have tested them in my apache in Linux machine with `curl` command as well as in browser. So what rules currently you have in htaccess?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. The site is giving me internal server error even after removing all the rules from htaccess. Without you code added, I've noticed that if I redirect to /? instead of /, the string is removed by the ? remains. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Ihfaz, can you please confirm if you are only using my htaccess code?

Comment: Yes, it's only yours. I need the other ones but still I gave it a go with your ones.

Comment: @Ihfaz, These are tested successfully ones and I am not seeing any `?` or anything with my shown rules. Can you please do explain what's going on when you hit rules?

Comment: @Ihfaz, Could you please do let me know on my previous comments? Thank you.